# The non-type template parameter of pointer to overloaded member functions with inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

## Background

Consider the following code:

```
struct A { // a class we want to hide from the client code
  int f();
  int f(char);
  int g();
};

struct B : A {}; // the interface class

// client code:
//
// It's natural to assume a member function of T should have
// a type of int (T::*)(), right?
template <typename T, int (T::*)()> struct F {};

// compiles, of course
F<A, &A::g> {};

// doesn't compile, because &B::g is not of type `int (B::*)()`, and no
// conversion is allowed here
F<B, &B::g> {};

// compiles, because &B::g is actually &A::g
//
// but this is not I want because the class hierarchy may be deep and it's
// not easy to know what A is.
F<A, &B::g> {};
```

The fragment `struct<B, &B::g> {}` doesn't compile because

1. The type of `&B::g` is `int (A::*)()`, rather than `int (B::*)()`;
2. Though an implicit conversion from `int (A::*)()` to `int (B::*)()` is legal and viable, the C++ standard forbids (!!) any conversion when doing the template arguments substitution for the point-to-member-function template parameter. (Strictly speaking, a conversion to `nullptr_t` is allowed.)

As a consequence, `F<B, &B::g>` cannot match the exact definition of `F` and it fails to compile. This is sad because `class A` may be the implementation detail we don't want to bother with.

## Workaround

A naive hack would be

```
template <typename T, T val> struct G {};

// at least compiles, and don't have to be aware of A
G<decltype(&B::g), &B::g> {};
```

so far so good.

## Problem

The above hack doesn't work with the overloaded class methods. Usually, the overloads can be resolved by static_cast, but this requires we know the exact type of &B::f -- a nice chick-and-egg situation.

```
// won't compile since &B::f is ambiguous
G<decltype(&B::f), &B::f> {};

// won't compile just like F<B, &B::g>
G<decltype(static_cast<int(B::*)()>(&B::f)), &B::f> {};

// compiles, but require the knowledge of the type of &B::f
G<decltype(static_cast<int(A::*)()>(&B::f)), &B::f> {};
```

Something like `G<decltype(static_cast<int(A::*)()>(&B::f)), &B::f> {};` is terrible.

To wrap up, the problem is how to correctly select a particular overload and avoid mentioning the base class `A` when `&B::f` is actually `&A::f`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It is probably easier to wrap all of this in non-member functions and forget about this `Foo (Bar::*)(Baz)` nightmare once and for all.

Comment: @n.m. yes it's nightmare and i can wrap them in many proxy functions to make it just work, but i wonder if it can be fixed by a convenient way.

Comment: @DDrmmr `F` is a simplification of `boost::multi_index::mem_fun`. I do want them to compile.

Comment: @subi Then you have already provided your own answer: use `F<A, &B::g>`. If you don't want to type that, use a non-member function to deduce the template arguments like n.m. suggested.

Comment: If `G<decltype(static_cast<int(B::*)()>(&B::f)), &B::f> {};` is convenient, then I don't know what isn't.

Comment: @n.m. `G<decltype(static_cast<int(B::*)()>(&B::f)), &B::f> {};` won't compile because `decltype(static_cast<int(B::*)()>(&B::f)) == int(B::*)()`, while `&B::f` is of type `int(A::*)()`. It doesn't match the definition of `G<typename T, T val>`.

Comment: @Jefffrey I want `F` used as `F<B,&B::g>` instead of `F<A,&B::g>` since the base class `A` is supposed to be hidden from user.

Comment: @DDrmmr Seems no choice left for me. I'll go with F<A, &B::g>.

Comment: @subi No, I mean, what are you doing within the F object? Why do you need the pointer as a constant expression?

Comment: @Jefffrey `F` is actually `boost::multi_index::mem_fun`, which is part of the definition of a container type, and thus needs to be a compile time constant.

Comment: `won't compile` I know. The point is that you have actually tried it, and probably would use it if it did compile. Yet line noise is only marginally less readable than that.

Comment: @n.m. Ah I misread your comment "is convenient" as "isn't convenient". My apology. Then I totally agree with you that we should avoid codes like `G<decltype(static_cast<int(B::*)()>(&B::f)), &B::f> {};`. Personally, even it would compile, I would choose `F<A, &B::f>` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround fitting my requirements. Hoping it be helpful for anyone in need. I got stuck for days...

The idea is using a function template to match a particular overload, and then pass the correct type to `G`. A layer of indirection always saves the world.

```
template <typename T>
auto forward_pmf_with_signature( int(T::*pmf)() ) -> decltype(pmf);

G<decltype(forward_pmf_with_signature(&B::f)), &B::f> {}; // works
```

`G` is used without the awareness of `A` and selects the correct overload, cool.

Now the new problem is that I found `G<decltype(forward_pmf_with_signature(&B::f)), &B::f>` is redundant and error-prone. It's trivial to use a macro `USE_G(&B::f)` to simply the code, but it seems to me that it's not easy, or even possible to do the simplification in a semantic way.

Comment: Good job, but you don't actually need a body for `forward_pmf_with_signature()`. You can leave it as a declaration instead since all the compiler needs is the return type.